# How to keep a service running even when app is cleared?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-intentservice

Is there a way to ensure a service will continue to run in the background after being started, even if the user clears the app from the recents screen? A perfect example would be Pandora's app, once it starts playing, even if you clear it from recents, the music keeps playing and the notification remains.

In my sample app I have a simple Handler that just logs the current time ever 500ms so I can see if the service is running, and I start it using one of 4 toggles, each set up to make it start with one of the 4 service start types (START_STICKY, START_NOT_STICKY, START_REDELIVER_INTENT, START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY). I start the service, exit the app, then clear it from recents. In each case the service dies and the loop logging stops.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Boolean recording = false;
    private Intent recordingService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recordingService = new Intent(this, RecordingService.class);

        Button START_STICKY = (Button) findViewById(R.id.START_STICKY);
        START_STICKY.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startStopRecordingService(Service.START_STICKY);
            }
        });

        Button START_NOT_STICKY = (Button) findViewById(R.id.START_NOT_STICKY);
        START_NOT_STICKY.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startStopRecordingService(Service.START_NOT_STICKY);
            }
        });

        Button START_REDELIVER_INTENT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.START_REDELIVER_INTENT);
        START_REDELIVER_INTENT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startStopRecordingService(Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT);
            }
        });

        Button START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY = (Button) findViewById(R.id.START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY);
        START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startStopRecordingService(Service.START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startStopRecordingService(int START_TYPE) {
        if (recording) {
            recordingService.removeExtra(RecordingService.START_TYPE);
            stopService(recordingService);
        } else {
            recordingService.putExtra(RecordingService.START_TYPE, START_TYPE);
            startService(recordingService);
        }

        recording = !recording;
    }
}
```

**RecordingService.java**

```
public class RecordingService extends Service
{
    public final static String START_TYPE = "START_TYPE";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID) {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "onStartCommand");

        int start_type = intent.getExtras().getInt(START_TYPE);
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "START_STICKY: " + String.valueOf(start_type == Service.START_STICKY));
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "START_NOT_STICKY: " + String.valueOf(start_type == Service.START_NOT_STICKY));
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "START_REDELIVER_INTENT: " + String.valueOf(start_type == Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT));
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY: " + String.valueOf(start_type == Service.START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY));

        logTime();

        return start_type;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "onDestroy");
        updateDisplayTimer.removeCallbacks(updateDisplayHandler);
    }

    public void logTime() {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        updateDisplayTimer.postDelayed(updateDisplayHandler, LOOP_TIME);
    }

    private static final int LOOP_TIME = 500;
    private Handler updateDisplayTimer = new Handler();
    private Runnable updateDisplayHandler = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            logTime();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implementing foreground service. [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Foreground service displays notification and is never stopped.

Implement this code snippet in your service

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```